# need advise on if-else statement using php

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to add `selected` in `option` when condition true. Its working fine, but its giving two times `selected`.

```
foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { 
    if ($cat_id == 59 && $sorts['value'] == 'p.price-ASC') { // True if category id equal to 59
        <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
    }else{
        if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { // True if values are equal
            <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        }else {
            <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        }
    }
}
```

In above you can see there are two conditions for `selected`.

1. True if category id equal to 59 `if ($cat_id == 59 &&
   $sorts['value'] == 'p.price-ASC')`
2. True if values are equal `if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' .
   $order)`

On other category pages it totally working fine, but on category `59` two `if statements` are giving `true`. That's why on this page two `selected` are adding on two `option`.

```
<option value="name-az" >Name (A - Z)</option>
<option value="name-az" selected="selected">Name (Z - A)</option>
<option value="p.price-ASC" selected="selected">Price (Low > High)</option>
```

So can any one guide me how to fix or modify the condition that i can get only one true condition in one time. Thanks

Comment: You can maybe fix it by adding an `break`, by doing this you can leave your foreach statement after your if statement has been true.

Comment: @uruloke But i need other options also without `selected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by using a new variable $done indicating that the selected value was added already:

```
$done = false;
foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { 
    if (!$done && $cat_id == 59 && $sorts['value'] == 'p.price-ASC') { // True if category id equal to 59
        <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        $done = true;
    }else{
        if (!$done && $sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { // True if values are equal
            <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
            $done = true;
        }else {
            <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        }
    }
}
```

Problem with the above and your code is that the foreach is incorrect. $sorts as $sorts is not possible for the foreach. I've refactored your code to more safe and better usable code. This code is also tested and works as expected:

```
//INPUT:

$sort = 'name';
$order = 'za';
$cat_id = 59;

$sorts = array(
    'name-az' => 'Name (A - Z)',
    'name-za' => 'Name (Z - A)',
    'p.price-ASC' => 'Price (Low > High)',
    'p.price-DESC' => 'Price (High > Low)'
);

//CODE:

if(!array_key_exists($sort . '-' . $order, $sorts)) //check your input!
    throw new Exception('Invalid sort order.');

$selected = $cat_id == 59 ? 'p.price-ASC' : $sort . '-' . $order;

$done = false;
echo '<select>';
foreach ($sorts as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($key, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'"'.($selected==$key?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Its giving same issue, two times selected on two options, it means still two statements are true

Comment: You must have missed something then when copying the code. Did you use the exact code above?

Comment: Ok let me double check again but i don't think i missed

Comment: Sorry, the variable should have been defined outside the foreach loop... changed the code see above

Comment: Yes i tried again but facing same issue. Can you create dummy code on local machine and check the logic. Because it is good logic, we may solve using this. Right now we are missing something.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and cooperation

Answer (score 0):

Why use 2 if statements?  That's what `elseif` is for.  Does this code work for you?

```
foreach($sorts as $sorts)
{ 
 if($cat_id == 59 && $sorts['value'] == 'p.price-ASC')
 {
  <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
  continue;
 }
 elseif($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order)
 {
  <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
  continue;
 }
 else
 {
  <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
 }
}
```

Comment: this won't work because they will still match each time

Comment: @Kapitein Witbaard - I think it's because there is an error in another part of the code.  Look at the 3 sample output lines.  The first 2 have the same value `name-az` when 1 of them should be `name-za`.  Instead of using the $done variable why not just use the php command `continue` to skip to the next iteration?